# C++: Behavior of abstract union and new placement operator?

Tags: c++, unions

It's my understanding a `union`'s size is that of the largest member on that union.  Does anyone know how a union behaves when a non-fixed size container such as a `string` is added to it?  What is the size?  Also, how does the size change when the new placement operation is used?  Thanks!

Here is an example:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class X {
public:
    union {
        int i;
        string s;
    };
    X(string ss) { new(&s) string{ss}; };
    ~X() { s.~string(); };
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    X xx{"abc"};

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(std::string)` never changes.  Also, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106941/is-a-union-members-destructor-called/40107282#40107282

Comment: Indeed, and you may be surprised to learn that `sizeof(std::string)` is always the same, whether the string is empty or holds the entire contents of all Harry Potter books.

Comment: Is that because the container string has some pointer to the string's actual data?

Comment: Practically, yes. Same thing for `std::vector`, and all other containers. The size of all objects in C++ never changes. This is fundamental, and `std::string` manages all the memory, correctly, for you. Same thing for containers. This is why modern C++ code rarely needs to use `new` or `delete`.

Comment: In that case, does this code need to use the new placement operation on construction?

Comment: Yes, it does. When a union contains non-PODs, you are responsible for correctly constructing and destroying union members, one at a time, and in order. But way force this headache upon yourself? Just use `std::variant` and it, too, will do all of this for you.

Comment: I strongly recommend Sam's suggest.  `union` is easy to get wrong, hard to get right, and  can easily cause a work-late-weekend.  `std::variant` is easy to get right, hard to get wrong, and can save you a lost weekend.  Unless you're optimizing for job security.

Comment: Thanks, I'm simply following Stroustrups C++ 4th Ed, around page 200.  So if `string` was declared in the class body, the new placement operation would NOT be required correct?

Comment: Correct. The only reason you need placement `new` here is the `union`. If you don't have to share storage between the `int` and the `string`, your life becomes whole orders of magnitude easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's my understanding a union's size is that of largest member on that union.

Not quite exactly. If one member has stricter alignment requirement, and another member is larger, but not a multiple of the mentioned alignment, then the total size of the union may be larger than either member.

> Does anyone know how a union behaves when a non fixed size container

There are no non-fixed size types in C++. All types have a compile time constant size. Dynamic containers allocate memory from the free store, and indirectly refer to that memory with constant sized pointers.

> What is the size?

It is exactly `sizeof(X)` bytes.

> Also, how does the size change when the new placement operation is used?

It does not change.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof(std::string) is always the same, whether the string is empty or holds a string.  The only reason the new placement operator is required is because of the string existing in the union, because storage is shared between the string and the int.