# Destructor of union member seems to be called automatically

Tags: c++, destructor, unions

I'm attempting to implement a tagged union.

My understanding was that in a C++ union, the non-trivial (i.e. not empty) destructors of non-static members are *never called*, thus we have to call them ourselves. That's what I did:

```
#include <iostream>

class C {
public:
  C() {
    std::cout << "C Ctor" << std::endl;
  }
  ~C() {
    std::cout << "C Dtor" << std::endl;
  }
};

class B {
public:
  B() {
    std::cout << "B Ctor" << std::endl;
  }
  ~B() {
    std::cout << "B Dtor" << std::endl;
  }
};

struct S {
  int type;

  union U {
    C c;
    B b;

    U() {

    }

    ~U() {}
  } u;

  S(int type) : type(type) {
    if (type == 0) {
      u.c = C();
    } else {
      u.b = B();
    }
  }

  ~S() {
    if (type == 0) {
      u.c.~C();
    } else {
      u.b.~B();
    }
  }
};

int main() {
  S s(0);
  return 0;
}
```

However, the output is:

```
C Ctor
C Dtor
C Dtor
```

Meaning, the `C` destructor is being called twice, instead of just once.

What is going on? And if you notice additional issues with my tagged union implementation, please point them out.

Comment: FYI: `std::endl` is usually unnecessary. `"\n"` is just as portable and doesn't try to flush the output at every line.

Comment: Typically you would use an *anonymous union* to implement a tagged union, you can read about these in the standard and/or check out the implementation of `std::variant`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In

```
S(int type) : type(type) {
    if (type == 0) {
      u.c = C();
    } else {
      u.b = B();
    }
  }
```

Since you are in the body of the constrcutor, `u.c = C();` is not initialization but is instead assigment.  That means you see the constructor called for `C()`, and then at the end of the expression the first destructor call is called to destroy that temporary. We can see this by adding

```
C& operator=(const C&) { std::cout << "operator=(const C&)\n"; return *this; }
```

to `C` which changes the output to

```
C Ctor
operator=(const C&)
C Dtor
C Dtor
```

Then the second destructor call is when `s` goes out of scope in main and its destructor is ran.

---

Do note that as is, the code has undefined behavior.  Unions do not activate a member in the constructor user provided constructor you wrote so when you do

```
u.c = C();
```

you are assigning to an object that is not yet alive.  You can't modify an object that isn't alive.

Comment: I see. So the destructor is called once for the temporary and only once for the member. Correct? If so - how would you suggest changing this? The reason I instantiate `C` in the body and not the initializer list is becasue I need to branch on the `type`... I guess I can do trinary operator in the initializer list, but is this common?

Comment: @AvivCohn Use placement `new` like `S(int type) : type(type) {
    if (type == 0) {
      new (&u.c) C();
    } else {
      new (&u.b) B();
    }
  }`.  That gives you `C Ctor
C Dtor` as the output.

Comment: @NathanOliver: You could also use a tool like [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/UzStsX) to view the code's disassembly and see where the deconstructor is called; works well for small examples like this.

Comment: @NathanOliver I see regarding placement new. Is it correct that the reason why this works is because it avoids creating an additional temporary on the stack?

Comment: @AvivCohn Correct.  It directly constructs the object the the memory the union occupies.

Comment: @AvivCohn If you want to see how to do this in production level code, take a look at one of the implementations of `std::variant`.  That is the C++ standard tagged union.

Comment: @AvivCohn The reason why your example doesn't work is because it has undefined behaviour, because it calls assignment operator of inactive union member that is non-trivially constructible. Nathan's suggestion (in comments) doesn't do that, and the behaviour is well defined.

Comment: @eerorika I see - I was about to make my peace with just creating a temporary on the stack like shown in the question. But, are you saying that it's actually illegal because assigning to a union which has not been constructed yet is UB? If I get that right, than the *only* way on C++ to assign a value to a union member which is not trivially-constructible and hasn't been constructed yet, is using placement new or the constructor initializer list. Correct?

Comment: @AvivCohn As far as I know yes, the only way to activate an inactive non-trivial union member is placement new.

Comment: @eerorika I learned something. Thanks! Coming from C, some stuff in C++ is surprisingly involved... in C this stuff takes you 3 minutes. I guess I have a lot more to learn.

Comment: Also, `u.c = C();` causes undefined behaviour since `u.c` is not the active member and has a user-provided constructor. (There is no active member since the union constructor was user-provided and did not set an active member). You can see in the output that `operator=` is called on an object that was never constructed. (as you point out, the previous constructor call is the temporary, not `u.c`)

Answer (score 2):

In your constructor you create the temporary instance of C:

```
u.c = C();
```

which is copied and then destructed. So, first 2 lines of output belong to this instance.
And the last output line is result of your ~S() call.

Besides this, beginning from C++17 you have standard powerful implementation of tagged union: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant