# Why would one wrap a struct in an anonymous union? (STL msvc implementation)

Tags: c++, templates, struct, unions, std

The STL `<memory>` header (MSVC implementation) contains a class called:

```
template <class _Ty> class _Ref_count_obj2 : public _Ref_count_base
```

This class has a member:

```
union {
    _Wrap<_Ty> _Storage;
};
```

where _Wrap is defined as:

```
template <class _Ty> 
struct _Wrap {
    _Ty _Value; // workaround for "T^ is not allowed in a union"
};
```

From my understanding, this code is designed to hold an object of type _Ty following its construction via the `new` operator. However I can't figure out why this was done; it seems like using a `struct` instead of a `struct` inside a `union` would work just as well.

Can anyone explain the reasoning behind this? Also, can anyone explain the comment in the _Wrap definition?

Comment: Making a `union` will prevent default destruction. Further, making it an *anonymous* union will move its member(s) names into the namespace of the enclosing scope.

Comment: @AdrianMole, but what is `T^`? Something from MS "managed C++"?

Comment: @Evg That's normally what `^` is in MSVC-world. However, the STL is most certainly *not* managed C++, and that is only in a comment, so it maybe just the implementer's shorthand for "reference" or some such. Dunno, really, which why I am hesitant about posting an answer.

Comment: @AdrianMole Here, `^` is indeed being used to refer to Managed C++ references. Even though STL isn't written in Managed C++, it has clients who are, and it uses the wrapper to accommodate those clients. (Plus, as you noted, the wrapper is needed even in standard C++ to deal with the case where the wrapped type is a reference.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, embedding the `_Storage` member in a `union` will prevent default destruction of that object (which is, more than likely, a *non-trivial* type); this appears to be essential, as the class involved is a reference counter. (By default, unions have a deleted destructor; see, for example: [Is a Union Member's Destructor Called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40106941/10871073) .)

Second, using an *anonymous* `union` 'moves' the `_Storage` identifier into the enclosing scope, thus removing any need for `X.`-style notation (if the union were to be named `X`). From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union):

> Members of an anonymous union are injected in the enclosing scope (and
> must not conflict with other names declared there).

Last, the need to wrap the union's member into a templated structure is so that the class will work with reference types, *which are not allowed in unions*. To check this last part out, try the following code with the commented-out lines made active:

```
template <class _Ty>
struct _Wrap {
    _Ty _Value; // workaround for "T^ is not allowed in a union"
};

template<class T>
class bob {
public:
    bob(T t) : uncle{t}//, aunty(t)
    {
    }
private:
    union {
        _Wrap<T> uncle;
    };
//    union {
//        T aunty;
//    };
};

int main()
{
    int i = 42;
    bob<int&> b{ i }; // Note: Template uses a REFERENCE type
    return 0;
}
```