# Referencing deleted destructor

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code:

```
struct Foo
{
    int type;
    union
    {
        int intValue;
        double doubleValue;
        std::wstring stringValue;
    } value;
};
```

and then in the cpp file I have:

```
std::vector<Foo> row;
some_class_object->func( row );
```

and I got:

```
error C2280: 'void *Foo::__delDtor(unsigned int)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

What is the problem here?

EDIT:

So I added this destructor:

```
~Foo()
{
    if( type ==3 )
        value.stringValue.~std::wstring();
}
```

and I got an error:

```
error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'wstring'.
```

Apparently std::string vs std::wstring matter in this case...

Didn't know about that.

EDIT2:

I am now getting:

```
 error C2280: 'Foo::<unnamed-type-value>::~<unnamed-type-value>(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Comment: Use `union` only to implement `variant`, then use it. Boost provides one for pre-C++17, std  provides since C++17.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The union contains a member (`std::string`) with a non-trivial destructor. This means that the union can't have a defaulted destructor (it wouldn't know which member's destructor to call). So you need to provide a custom destructor.

In your case define a union destructor that does nothing and then do the work in the struct destructor:

```
struct Foo {
    int type;

    union U {
        int intValue;
        double doubleValue;
        std::wstring stringValue;

        
        ~U() noexcept {}

    } value;

    ~Foo()
    {
        using std::wstring;

        if (type == 3)
            value.stringValue.~wstring();
    }
};
```

Please note that you need to do this for copy/move constructor/assignments as well.

In C++17 you have [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) which is a safe union.

Comment: so how do I write it? I am not using pointers, just a plain members.And I'm not there yet - I don't have C++17 compilers across platforms...

Comment: @Igor "*so how do I write it?*" - see [Is a Union Member's Destructor Called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40106941/)

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I updated the OP with the code I tried and the error I got.

Comment: @Igor drop the `std::`, it is not part of the destructor's name: `value.stringValue.~wstring();` Just make sure you had used `new(&value.stringValue) wstring();` beforehand

Comment: @Igor `using std::wstring; value.stringValue.~wstring();`

Comment: @bolov, I edited an OP with the new error.

Answer (score 0):

THE UNION has destructor deleted and you're attempting to use it as anonymous entity. You can't define destructor there without naming the type.

```
struct Foo
{
    int type;
    union ValueType
    {
        int intValue;
        double doubleValue;
        std::wstring stringValue;
        ~ValueType() {}
    } value;
    ~Foo();
};

Foo::~Foo()
{
    if( type ==3 )
        value.stringValue.std::wstring::~wstring();
}
```

It's far better to use standard tagged union template provided with compiler instead of rolling your own because of arcane code like this.

Comment: what is union template? Can you give a code sample or link documentation?