# Is it safe to use a current object within the storage of a destroyed object?

Tags: c++, constructor, language-lawyer, lifetime

In this code example, an object is created within the storage of another object using placement new, and freed memory is never accessed.

Here's the sequence of events:

1. New Object1 is created in allocated memory. Object2 is a union, so is not touched.
2. Object2 is created inside Object1 using placement new
3. Object1 is destroyed.  Object2 is untouched.
4. Contents of object2 are printed
5. Object2 destructor is called
6. Memory for Object1 is deleted

Is this safe?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <new>

struct Object2
{
    char a{1};
    char b{2};
    char c{3};
};

struct Object1
{
    //
    // disconnect Object2 lifetime from Object1
    //
    
    union
    {
        Object2 o;
    };

    char d{3};

    Object1()
    {
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    //
    // Create object1, internal object2 is not yet constructed
    //
    
    Object1* object1 = new Object1();

    //
    // create object2 inside object1 using placement new
    //

    new (&object1->o) Object2();

    Object2* object2 = &object1->o;

    //
    // Destroy object1, but do not free memory, and do not touch object2
    //

    object1->~Object1();

    //
    // Access alive object2 inside object2's memory
    //

    printf("a,b,c=(%d,%d,%d)\n", object2->a, object2->b, object2->c);

    //
    // Destroy object2
    //

    object2->~Object2();
    
    //
    // Destructor has already been called, so safe to delete delete memory without calling destructor
    //

    operator delete(object1);
}
```

Comment: There's going to be a really interesting story behind this question...

Comment: Once you destroy an object you cannot use any of its members, even if you know for certain that the memory still exists.

Comment: @MarkRansom Neither the anonymous union nor the variant member `Object2 o;` are formally destroyed

Comment: But they are still members of a destroyed object. Probably works as expected, but not kosher.

Comment: @Artyer I'm pretty sure I see some destructors being called in that code.  As you point out though the comments and code disagree with each other, so it's hard to know what was intended.

Comment: In the code, you try to read data in  `object1->o` after having destroyed it, it's an UB. When you destroy `object1`, that will destroy again  `object1->o` , it's an UB. Then after you delete `object1` which will destroy `object1` for 2nd time and `object1->o`  for 3rd time, it's an UB. ALL types are trivially destroyable so may seems to work, but:

Comment: FWIW, only clang seems to think this is UB: https://godbolt.org/z/Tnxd3oTP4 (but it might be that gcc and msvc are bugged)

Comment: Apologies I fixed the errors in the original code. @Artyer

Comment: i think with the errors fixed, this is actually all defined behavior and, well, kind of safe.  Not a recommended practice for sure. Calling the destructor does not free memory. The union, if more complex, may change the contents, but that's another question.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Why would the union change its contents if the containing object's destructor is executed? As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40107282/3150802), the union's destructor is actually deleted, so it is not called. Of course, `~Object1()` can overwrite any member's memory (and more) but so can any other (member or not) function, so that is not really relevant to the discussion.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica not in this example it wouldn't. By "if more complicated" I meant if there were actually more things in the union than in this example, which would cause them to be sharing the same memory. unions can result in a lot of unexpected bugs, so it is odd that it is used here at all.

Comment: The reason a union is used is because it prevents construction or destruction of Object2 when Object1 is constructed and destroyed respectively.